# Properly configure fail2ban for ssh server in docker container

Tags: iptables, docker, fail2ban

I have a configuration based fail2ban. I am running a container that runs an SSH service, and I am seeing a lot of "strange" connections. I have set docker to send the log of the container to Systemd's journal, and I am using it as a source for fail2ban. This is the filter I am using in F2B:

```
[sshd_docker]
enabled = true
port    = 22
filter = sshd[__prefix_line="^\s*\S+\s+[^[]+\[\w+\]:[^\]]+\]:\s+", __pref="", journalmatch="CONTAINER_NAME=sshdocker"]
action_ = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, bantime="%(bantime)s", port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="DOCKER-USER"]
```

As a matter of fact, this filter works, as I can see the following in IPtables:

```
# iptables -t filter -L FORWARD
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt   source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
[....]

# iptables -t filter -L DOCKER-USER
Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source            destination
f2b-sshd_docker  tcp  --  anywhere    anywhere   multiport dports ssh
[....]

#iptables -t filter -L f2b-sshd_docker
Chain f2b-sshd_docker (1 references)
target     prot opt source       destination
REJECT     all  --  96.9.168.71  anywhere   reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  94.96.68.78  anywhere   reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
[....]
```

I think fail2ban is setting properly the chain in iptables and that it is updating them properly. However, I still see in the log of the container the incoming connections get through, although being banned (https://pastebin.com/K3EwQMGG).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert with Docker, but if the connections are targeted to the machine itself, you probably should add your iptables rule to the INPUT chain instead of the FORWARD chain.
But this might be different with Docker...